# Azure function IoTHub: Error indexing method Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

Am trying to set a trigger from an Azure function to read all data that comes from my IoT hub. For that, I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=java#example).

After setting the connection string inside my local settings, when I try to launch my function, I get the following error:

> The 'functionName' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.functionName'. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').

I have tried to add the endpoint as a servicebus, or directly as a hostname, but in both I have the same error.

- As ServiceBus: **Endpoint=sb://{hubname}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={keyname};SharedAccessKey={accesskeyname};**
- As hostname: **HostName={hostName}.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName={keyname};SharedAccessKey={accesskeyname}**

To add further clarify, I will show my implementation:

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
        "app_trigger_hub_name": "{hubname}",
        "app_trigger_connection": "Endpoint=sb://{hubname}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={accessKey};SharedAccessKey={sharedKey}",
    }
}
```

**Azure Function trigger**

```
 @FunctionName("functionName")
  public void eventHubProcessor(
  @EventHubTrigger(name = "functionName", eventHubName = "%app_trigger_hub_name%",
  connection = "app_trigger_connection") String message,
  final ExecutionContext context) {
  context.getLogger().info(message);
  }
```

**[Credentials from azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/palZw.png)**

**EDIT**

After some trial & error I managed to get the connection using the servicebus, but still not working. Now when I start the function, I got the following error:

> The listener for function 'Functions.function' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor: Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds. System.Private.CoreLib: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using a IoTHub or a EventHub?
In C# you use the iothub attribute: "IoTHubTrigger".

E.g:

```
@FunctionName("ehprocessor")
public void eventHubProcessor(
  @IoTHubTrigger(name = "msg",
                  eventHubName = "myeventhubname",
                  connection = "myconnvarname") String message,
       final ExecutionContext context )
       {
          context.getLogger().info(message);
 }
```

```
using IoTHubTrigger = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubTriggerAttribute;
```

And for the connectionString you use the "Event Hub compatible endpoint", that you can find under "Built-in endpoints" in the azure portal.

I saw your edited part now, have you tried to empty your eventhub container locally? "azure-webjobs-eventhub"? that have solved many wierd errors for me.

Comment: I totally forgot about this. What I did was using a Built-in endpoint as the connection String.

Comment: @maro01507 cool, so you have solved the problem? :)

Comment: yep, thanks for trying to help anyway.